# Enum getting cast to string when bound with custom converter

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, enums, ivalueconverter

## Problem Overview

I have a custom `IValueConverter` called `EnumDisplayConverter`. It's supposed to take an `Enum` value and return the name so it can be displayed. Somehow, even though this converter is being used on a binding between properties of an `Enum` type, the converter is being passed a value of `String.Empty`. This of course causes an error as `String` is not an `Enum`, not to mention it's just really unexpected.

## Code to Reproduce

The following code can be used to reproduce the error. The steps to reproduce and an explanation of what the code is meant to do come after.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VBTest"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

    <DockPanel>
        <ListBox Name="LB_Foos" DockPanel.Dock="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding FooOptions}" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged"/>
        
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Static local:MainWindow.SelectableThings}" SelectedItem="{Binding OpenFoo.SelectableChosenThing}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="100">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl>
                        <ContentControl.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                                <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Converter={x:Static local:EnumDisplayConverter.Instance}}"/>

                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="-1">
                                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="None"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </ContentControl.Style>
                    </ContentControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </DockPanel>    
</Window>
```

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.Globalization

Class MainWindow

    Shared Sub New()
        Dim Things = (From v As Thing In [Enum].GetValues(GetType(Thing))).ToList
        Things.Insert(0, -1)
        SelectableThings = New ReadOnlyCollection(Of Thing)(Things)
    End Sub

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property SelectableThings As IReadOnlyList(Of Thing)

    Public ReadOnly Property FooOptions As New ReadOnlyCollection(Of Integer)({1, 2, 3, 4})

    'This is a placeholder method meant to set OpenFoo to a new instance of Foo when a selection is made.
    'In the actual application, this is done with data binding and involves async database calls.
    Private Sub ListBox_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs)
        OpenFoo = Nothing

        Select Case LB_Foos.SelectedItem
            Case 1
                OpenFoo = New Foo With {.ChosenThing = Nothing}
            Case 2
                OpenFoo = New Foo With {.ChosenThing = Thing.A}
            Case 3
                OpenFoo = New Foo With {.ChosenThing = Thing.B}
            Case 4
                OpenFoo = New Foo With {.ChosenThing = Thing.C}
        End Select
    End Sub

    Public Property OpenFoo As Foo
        Get
            Return GetValue(OpenFooProperty)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Foo)
            SetValue(OpenFooProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Shared ReadOnly OpenFooProperty As DependencyProperty =
                           DependencyProperty.Register("OpenFoo",
                           GetType(Foo), GetType(MainWindow))
End Class

Public Enum Thing
    A
    B
    C
End Enum

Public Class Foo

    Public Property ChosenThing As Thing?

    Public Property SelectableChosenThing As Thing
        Get
            Return If(_ChosenThing, -1)
        End Get
        Set(value As Thing)
            Dim v As Thing? = If(value = -1, New Thing?, value)
            ChosenThing = v
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

Public Class EnumDisplayConverter
    Implements IValueConverter

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Instance As New EnumDisplayConverter

    Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
        If value Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
        Return [Enum].GetName(value.GetType, value)
    End Function

    Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.ConvertBack
        Return Binding.DoNothing
    End Function
End Class
```

## Steps to Reproduce

1. Run `MainWindow`
2. Select any item from the `ListBox` on the left
3. Select a different item from the `ListBox`
4. Observe unhanded exception

## Code Explanation

In case it's not clear what the code is supposed to do, I'll explain a bit.

`Foo` represents a data object that is being edited by the user via `MainWindow`. Every `Foo` has the option of a `Thing`. *Not* having a `Thing` is also an option, which is why `ChosenThing` is a `Thing?` (i.e. `Nullable(Of Thing)`).

`Null` data items don't work in a `ComboBox`, since `Null` means "there is no selection". To get around this, I add a value of `-1` to my list of selectable `Thing` values. In `Foo.SelectableChosenThing`, I check for `-1` and convert it to `Null` for the actual value of `Foo.ChosenThing`. This lets me bind to the `ComboBox` correctly.

## Problem Details

The error only seems to occur when `OpenFoo` is set to `Nothing` before being given a new value. If I take out the line `OpenFoo = Nothing`, everything works. However, in the real application I *want* to set `OpenFoo` to `Nothing` while the selection is being loaded- besides, it doesn't explain why this is happening in the first place.

*Why* is `EnumDisplayConverter` being passed a `value` of type `String`, when the properties involved are of the expected type `Thing`?

Comment: What about defining two enums, one for the backing field `ChosenThing`, and one just for the UI, which includes a "nothing" value (set to -1)?  You already have a separate property which is bound to the combobox, where you can 'translate' between backing field enum and UI enum.  Then you wouldn't be setting `OpenFoo = Nothing`, but instead `OpenFoo = New Foo With { .SelectableChosenThing = ThingEnumForUI.Nothing }`.  I do realize this doesn't answer your _why_ question (hence it's a comment), but it might work around your issue.

Comment: @SeanSkelly In the full application, having `OpenFoo` set to `Nothing` means that no `Foo` instance is currently being edited. This is used in the app's logic.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, after some investigation, that the problem comes from the `ComboBox` control. When the selected item of the `ComboBox` is `null`, it replaces the display value of `null` with `String.Empty`. Here's a snippet from the [.NET Reference Source for `ComboBox.UpdateSelectionBoxItem`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/windows/Controls/ComboBox.cs,667a7cd66ecbac16):

```
...

// display a null item by an empty string
if (item == null)
{
    item = String.Empty;
    itemTemplate = ContentPresenter.StringContentTemplate;
}
 
SelectionBoxItem = item;
SelectionBoxItemTemplate = itemTemplate;

...
```

This happens before any `DataTemplate`s are considered, so by the time my `DataTemplate` get's called, it's being given a value of `String.Empty` to display instead of `null`.

The solution is to either

- Add a `DataTrigger` to the `ContentControl`'s `Style` which checks for `String.Empty` and doesn't use the converter in such a case.
- Modify `EnumDisplayConverter` to check for non-`Enum` values and return `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`.